# Help fitting a poisson glmer (getting an error message)

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a Poisson glmer model in R, to determine if 4 experimental 
treatments affected the rate at which plants developed new branches over time. 
New branches were counted after 35, 70 and 83 days and data were organised as follows:

```
treatment  replicate.plant  time      branches 
   a         ID4             35          0           
   a         ID4             70          1        
   a         ID4             83          1
   a         ID12            35          1
   a         ID12            70          3
   a         ID12            83          8
```

Loading the package `lme4`, I ran the following model:

```
mod<-glmer(branches ~ treatment + (1|time),
             family=poisson, 
             data=dataset)
```

but I obtain the following error message:

> Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) :
>   object '.setDummyField' not found

Can anyone please give me an indication of why I am getting this error 
and what does it mean?
Any advicse on how to make this model run will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although I am new here, this probably should be asked tagged as an R question instead of on Cross-Validated. At that time, consider making a small, reproducible example and give more information about your particular R session

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, see here: https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/54

The problem seems to be limited to `R` version `3.0.0`. You should update to a more recent version.

Comment: @Sandy: if this answer solves your problem, you are encouraged to click on the check-mark next to the answer to accept it ...